# LinkedIn iOS SDK Bundle Suffix

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

So, I have multiple bundles identifiers on my LinkedIn App Account. For each one of them, I've also created an URL Suffix Schemes.

The way I'm setting my URL types is like `li{appID}{suffix}`, where `{appID}` is the Application Id number as provided on LinkedIn and `{suffix}` is a short string I've defined for my app.

**The problem is: LinkedIn apparently doesn't recognize the suffix and chooses any app that has `li{appID}` set as an URL type. Is there any way I can fix this?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try formatting your types like:  `li{appID}-{suffix}`

Comment: Hi Justin, the following scheme doesn't work. When I trigger the login call, it goes to the LinkedIn app and never shows any login screen or even returns to our app.

Answer (score 3):

I have try given types like:  li{appID}-{suffix}
But not getting callback from linkedin to my app.

Comment: The same is happening to me.

Comment: I have the same problem. Are the LinkedIn developers aware of this problem?

Comment: @Devos50 They are, but apparently do not care. Big companies.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using url scheme suffix, make sure it is specified in the Info.plist. The key should be "LISuffix" and the value should be the suffix. Also, register a url scheme with the format li(appId)-(suffix).