# Linkedin SDK issue in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, linkedin-api

i am using Linkedin SDK in ios.
    i am using following code to authenticate the user

```
    [LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, nil]
                                 state:nil//@"some state"
                                 showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
                                           successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {

                                           }
                                             errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                                             }
 ];
```

by using this code , i am able to open linkedin app but unable to get callback from linkedin app to my app.
Not Getting call on

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

NSLog(@"%s url=%@","app delegate application openURL called ", [url absoluteString]);
if ([LISDKCallbackHandler shouldHandleUrl:url]) {
    return [LISDKCallbackHandler application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
return YES;
```

}

i am using "liMY_APPID" in URL Schemes.And also try from [LinkedIn iOS SDK Bundle Suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671488/linkedin-ios-sdk-bundle-suffix/32753513#32753513)
Please help me how i can get callback from linkedin app

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: check my answer . I reslove it successfully

Answer (score 7):

Make sure if you are using iOS 9.0 or higher as base SDK since

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
         annotation:(id)annotation
```

is deprecated from iOS 9. Instead use

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                             id> *)options
```

Use `options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey]` and `options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey]` for sourceApplication and annotation respectively.

**Example:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    if ([LISDKCallbackHandler shouldHandleUrl:url]) {
        return [LISDKCallbackHandler application:app openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey]];
    }
    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct only but your problem is related to URL schemes...

Add the same URL scheme in your `info.plist` file what you have mentioned in "**iOS URL Suffix Schemes**" so that once linkedIn will call the same URL scheme, Might be you have used incorrect URL scheme in your app.

[image]

URL scheme is nothing but it is a link to open your application. If you enter your URL scheme in mobile safari i.e.

> testApp://

it will open your app (If installed). Using following process you can add it in your project

right-click on your `info.plist` and choose Open As – *Source Code*:

[image]

right-click on your `info.plist` and select *Show Raw Keys/Values*, the output will look as follows:

[image]

check link for more details to add [custom URL schemes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov7wh.gif)

Comment: is it only possible with Linkedin v1?

Answer (score 2):

ISSUE RESOLVED

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

         if LISDKCallbackHandler.shouldHandle(url) {
                LISDKCallbackHandler.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
            }

            return true
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the LIAppId property to your Info.plist?

Comment: If you're using url scheme suffix, make sure it is specified in the Info.plist. The key should be "LISuffix" and the value should be the suffix. Also, register a url scheme with the format li<appId>-<suffix>

Answer (score -1):

Have you added all your bundles to LinkedIn dev's center for iOS? If not, copy your bundle id and add it to https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/APP_ID/mobile and do not forget to **Save**.

Comment: All bundles entry is correct.And given link is not opening.

Comment: I have the same issue. Everything is correctly filled in but the LinkedIn app does not return control to my app.